# What is difference between IntentService and HandlerThread?

Tags: android, android-intent

They both loop through a queue of something (messages/intents) and execute them?

Answer (score 1):

IntentService is not really loop through a queue of Intents, It uses the `Service` to receive Intents and handle it in a worker thread, Actually, there is a `HandlerThread` running in `IntentService` doing the loop stuff.